# how to form tree database structure using lmdb

Tags: python, graph, lmdb, okvs

Here I'm trying to create graph database whose structure will look following. As I keep adding more nodes, I don't see the `depth of the tree increasing`. Can one suggest what I might be doing wrong here?

```
       A:1
     /    \
    B:2   C:3
  /          \
D:4          E:5

    >>> import lmdb
    >>> env = lmdb.open("treedb.lmdb")
    >>> txn = env.begin(write = True)
    >>> txn.stat()
    {'psize': 4096, 'depth': 0, 'branch_pages': 0, 'leaf_pages': 0, 'overflow_pages': 0, 'entries': 0}
    >>> txn.put('root'.encode('utf-8'),json.dumps({'A':1}).encode('utf-8'))
    True
    >>> txn.stat()
    {'psize': 4096, 'depth': 1, 'branch_pages': 0, 'leaf_pages': 1, 'overflow_pages': 0, 'entries': 1}
    
    >>> txn.put('A'.encode('utf-8'), json.dumps({'A':{'B':2}}).encode('utf-8'))
    True
    >>> txn.stat()
    {'psize': 4096, 'depth': 1, 'branch_pages': 0, 'leaf_pages': 1, 'overflow_pages': 0, 'entries': 2}
    >>>
    >>> txn.put('A'.encode('utf-8'), json.dumps({'A':{'C':3}}).encode('utf-8'))
    True
    >>>
    >>> txn.stat()
    {'psize': 4096, 'depth': 1, 'branch_pages': 0, 'leaf_pages': 1, 'overflow_pages': 0, 'entries': 3}
    >>>
    >>> txn.put('B'.encode('utf-8'), json.dumps({'B':{'D':4}}).encode('utf-8'))
    True
    >>> txn.put('C'.encode('utf-8'), json.dumps({'C':{'E':5}}).encode('utf-8'))
    >>> txn.stat()
{'psize': 4096, 'depth': 1, 'branch_pages': 0, 'leaf_pages': 1, 'overflow_pages': 0, 'entries': 5}
```

Comment: I keep adding more childs but still the tree remains flat. Almost it is just a key:value DB instead of graph. I must be missing something which I don't understand.

Comment: Do you need traversal queries only? Or you need to also query by properties?

Comment: traversal query only

Answer (score 0):

First it is unclear what you are trying to achieve with `txn.stats`.

Second, `str.encode` is the "poor man" packing function, you need lexicographic packing into bytes preserving natural type order (ref: [python:`fdb.tuples.pack`](https://github.com/apple/foundationdb/blob/main/design/tuple.md))

If you want to go from a parent to children and back, given the following tree:

```
a
|_b
|_c
|_d
|_e
  |_f
  |_g
  |_h
```

Given the following notation `key -> value`, you can build the following okvs schema:

```
a -> properties
a.b -> properties
a.c -> properties
a.d -> properties
a.e -> properties
a.e.f -> properties
a.e.g -> properties
a.e.h -> properties
```

If say, you have the node `a.e.g` you can retrieve the parent by removing the last component to obtain `a.e`, then to query all children of `a.e`, you query the range of keys that have as prefix (startswith) `a.e.`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69317404/140837

Really the dot `.` as separator is a hack, look into [`python-lexode`](https://github.com/amirouche/python-lexode).