# How do I specify a Range including everything in a RocksDB column?

Tags: rocksdb

I want to publish metrics about my RocksDB instance, including the disk size of each column over time. I've come across a likely API method to calculate disk size for a column:

[GetApproximateSizes()](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Approximate-Size):

> `Status s = GetApproximateSizes(options, column_family, ranges.data(), NUM_RANGES, sizes.data());`

This is a nice API, but I don't know how to provide a `Range` that will specify my entire column. Is there a way to do so without finding the min/max key in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the whole database, you can approximate it using `0x00` or the empty byte string and an arbitrarily big key as end such as `0xFFFFFF`.

Otherwise, if the column share a common prefix, use the following function to compute the end key:

```py
def strinc(key):
    key = key.rstrip(b"\xff")
    return key[:-1] + int2byte(ord(key[-1:]) + 1)
```

`strinc` will compute the next byte string that is not prefix of key, together they describe the whole keyspace having `KEY` as prefix.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify: do the two `Slice`'s passed to `Range` act as prefixes for the `Range` lookup? Or do they fully define the start and end key? E.g. for set `[A, AA, B, BA]`, does `Range(A, B)` return `[A, AA, B]` or `[A, AA, B, BA]`?

Comment: If the prefix is `ABC` you must call `range(ABC, strinc(ABC))` it describe the range `[ABC, strinc(ABC)[` that is `strinc(ABC)` is excluded from the range because `strinc(ABC)` does not start with ABC.

Comment: Does it makes sense?

Comment: I assume by `Slice` you mean a string of bytes, then I think you go it. Except a range is a range, from point A to point B. `strinc(ABC)` will compute the immediatly next byte string that is not prefix of `ABC`. So `Range(ABC, strinc(ABC))` describe the range of key that starts with / have the prefix `ABC`.

Comment: `Range(0x0A, 0x0B)` will return `0x0A, 0x0A00, 0x0A01, .... 0x0AFFFFFF...` possibly it will also return the end key `0x0B` but not further down the keyspace (no 0x0B00 or 0x0B01...)

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver please mark my answer as good answer if it is the case. If there is something unclear I can expand the answer. I can also elaborate why `strinc` helps to retrieve a range of key that starts with a given prefix?

Comment: Nope your clarification of how Range's arguments work cleared it up for me! Thanks for the answer :)